# How to count objects from database filtered by a choice field in django?

Tags: python, django

I have Porumbei model and it has gender field. In template I must render the number of Porumbei of each gender. For example: Male= x Porumbei, Female= y Porumbei and Unknown = z Porumbei.

## My model

```
class Porumbei(models.Model):
    SEXE = [
        ('Mascul', 'Mascul'),
        ('Femelă', 'Femelă'),
        ('Pui', 'Pui')
    ]
    ...
    gender = models.CharField(max_length=6, choices=SEXE, db_index=True)
    ...
```

For Total I have:

```
total = Porumbei.objects.count()
```

Below is what I have now:

```
@staticmethod
def masculi(crescator=None):
    """ Numarul de masculi din sistem """
    mascul = Porumbei.objects.filter(gender="Mascul", is_active=True, crescator=crescator)
    return len(mascul)

@staticmethod
def femele(crescator=None):
    """ Numarul de femele din sistem """
    femela = Porumbei.objects.filter(gender="Femelă", is_active=True, crescator=crescator)
    return len(femela)

@staticmethod
def pui(crescator=None):
    """ Numarul de pui din sistem """
    pui = Porumbei.objects.filter(gender="Pui", is_active=True, crescator=crescator)
    return len(pui)
```

These functions gets me what I want but from my point of view, are not well optimized. This will end up in three similar queries as I saw in django debug toolbar. My question is, how can I get the number of each gender in only one query. Is it possible with another method or this function can be optimized to do a single query in database? I must mention that with the number of each gender, arithmetic operations must be performed. For example, how much of the total is each gender.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

You can use `values()`, and `annotate()` to run a `GROUP BY` on `gender` field, and then get count.

```
from django.db.models import Count

gender_count = Porumbei.objects.values('gender').annotate(count=Count('gender')).order_by()
```

`order_by()` is an optional clause here, but it should be added when default ordering is defined for the `Model`. From [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/#interaction-with-default-ordering-or-order-by):

> Fields that are mentioned in the `order_by()` part of a queryset (or which are used in the default ordering on a model) are used when selecting the output data, even if they are not otherwise specified in the `values()` call. These extra fields are used to group “like” results together and they can make otherwise identical result rows appear to be separate. This shows up, particularly, when counting things.

Adding `order_by()` in the end clears any default ordering.

> How can I render this into template?

`gender_count` dictionary  will contain `gender` values as key, and corresponding count as value.

To render, `gender_count` in template you can iterate over the dict.

```
{% for gender, count in gender_count.items %} 
    <p>{{gender}}: {{count}}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This part  {% for gender, count in gender_count.items %} 
    <p>{{gender}}: {{count}}</p>
{% endfor %}  It gets me: {gender: Pui, count: 1}, {gender: Pui, count:1} and so on

Comment: I need Pui= Pui total, Mascul= Mascul total, Femela=Femela total

Comment: Do you have default ordering defined in `Meta` `class` of `Porumbei` model? In that case, you will have to add `order_by()` after `annotate()`.

Comment: It gets me gender: count three times

Comment: @Alex You mean 3 times for each `gender` (total 9 items), or 1 time for each `gender` (total 3 items)?

Comment: One time for each gender `gender: count`, `gender: count`, `gender: count` total 3 times

Comment: That is what you want, no? From your question: <My question is, how can I get the number of each gender in only one query.......For example, how much of the total is each gender>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211618/discussion-between-alex-and-narendra-choudhary).